# Create multiple dataframe columns containing calculated values from an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `sega_df`:

```
Month            2016-11-01     2016-12-01
Character                                                        
Sonic            12.0            3.0
Shadow           5.0             23.0
```

I would like to create multiple new columns, by applying a formula for each already existing column within my dataframe (to put it shortly, pretty much double the number of columns). That formula is `(100 - [5*eachcell])*0.2`.

For example, for November for Sonic, `(100-[5*12.0])*0.2 = 8.0`, and December for Sonic, `(100-[5*3.0])*0.2 = 17.0` My ideal output is:

```
Month            2016-11-01     2016-12-01     Weighted_2016-11-01    Weighted_2016-12-01
Character                                                        
Sonic            12.0            3.0           8.0                    17.0
Shadow           5.0             23.0          15.0                   -3.0
```

I know how to create a for loop to create one column. This is for if only *one* month was in consideration:

```
for w in range(1,len(sega_df.index)):
    sega_df['Weighted'] = (100 - 5*sega_df)*0.2
    sega_df[sega_df < 0] = 0
```

I haven't gotten the skills or experience yet to create *multiple* columns. I've looked for other questions that may answer what exactly I am doing but haven't gotten anything to work yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious, why are you working with wide data? Here, dates should be its own column with values adjacent to it. Computation and wrangling are much difficult for wide datasets. Reshape to long format, run your needed aggregations without loops, and life is easier.

Comment: @Parfait I applied `.sum()` and `.groupby()` previously after reading the excel sheet in. My original Excel sheet has multiple entries per character per month, so yes, dates had their own column before, and I wanted to get the number of rows down to the number of unique characters. This is so I can see trends on a month-by-month basis, just for my own interests. I only copied the first two months and first two characters to keep my post short. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Wide format is usually for end-use reporting needs and should be the last step. Once again, import from Excel, reshape to long format using `melt`, then run your aggregations/computations. No looping needed or maintenance of many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One vectorised approach is to drown to `numpy`:

```
A = sega_df.values
A = (100 - 5*A) * 0.2

res = pd.DataFrame(A, index=sega_df.index, columns=('Weighted_'+sega_df.columns))
```

Then join the result to your original dataframe:

```
sega_df = sega_df.join(res)
```

Comment: This works, except the `columns` argument spits out a TypeError (`must be str, not DatetimeIndex`), because my columns are actually of type `DateTime` from reading it in from Excel. Currently working on getting the column names assigned correctly and avoiding errors like this.

Comment: Yep, if you're going to be prefixing column names, you probably want them all strings before you  start. Something like `df.columns = df.columns.map(str)`.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for converting column headers into string?

Comment: @ia_wing, Yes, see my previous comment.